Laravel v11 CSRF token mismatch
I am trying to enable cors for my frontend Angular application (previously used with Kotlin + Spring boot backend) to be able to make a post request for registering users but I get CSRF token mismatch error.
So far I have tried to add a middleware which would allow all origins and then apply that middleware on the url POST request. This is how my middleware class looks like:
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');

        return $response;
    }
}

and here is the route definition
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
Route::middleware('cors')->group(function () {
        Route::post('auth/artist/register', [\App\Http\Controllers\ArtistRegisterController::class, 'registerArtist']);
    });
});


and in the Kernel.php class file i added
 protected $middleware = ['cors' => Cors::class];
the angular service method that makes the call is as follows:
 registerArtist(formData: FormData
    ): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.post<Jwt | undefined>(`${this.baseUrl}/artist/register`, formData)
            .pipe(
                map(value => {
                    if (value && value.jwt) {
                        localStorage.setItem("jwt", value.jwt);
                        this.isUserLoggedInSubject.next(true);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            )
    }

I don't need jwt authentication in Laravel, but I don't think that is an issue at all in the post request.
This is my first Laravel project so I am not sure what I am doing that is wrong. Since I am using version 11 of Laravel, I haven't managed to find an answer to my problem.

CORS and anti-CSRF tokens are separate things.  CORS header should only be sent in response to OPTIONS request from the browser.  (This is called a "pre-flight" and is sent and responded to BEFORE the actual request is made.)  You should absolutely not wildcard allowed origins.  (in fact whenever you respond with CORS headers you are decreasing the security of your site and making CSRF attacks more likely)  So CORS has nothing to do with your CSRF token mismatch error.  To help with that we'd need to see your front-end and back-end middleware concerning the anti-CSRF token.

For angular side of things, it's pretty easy to setup it's middleware... you'd use HttpClientXsrfModule: https://v17.angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule  It will read a non-httponly, same-site cookie set by the server and set the header for each request.  (be sure to use relative paths for your requests, as it won't work for absolute paths)
